# Разделить сплошной текст на страницы

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, winrt

Исходная ситуация: Есть текст из .txt файла. 
Задача зная все параметры (ширина, высота, шрифт и т.п.) отдельно взятой страницы (отображается через RichTextBlock/TextBlock) сформировать из исходного текста массив string в каждом из элементов которого будет храниться тексту не более чем умещается в элемент отображения. (другими словами разделить текст на страницы)

Пробовал использовать свойство `RichTextBlock.HasOverflowContent`, поочерёдно добавляя по слову в контрол и формируя очередную страницу когда контент выходит за рамки (т.е. весь добавленный текст до изменения свойства и есть целая страница) Но при таком подходе выходит неприемлимо долго если текст большой (например книга)

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы используете линейный поиск, а нужно [двоичный][1]. Правда в вашей задаче основную сложность вызывает нахождение начального значения для правого конца перед запуском поиска. Очевидно можно брать конец книги, но это расточительно и будет не сильно лучше простого поиска. Для этого можно придумать какую-нибудь эвристику.  

[1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA

Comment: А если слово не входит полностью в строку, его можно разбивать? Или надо переносить на следующую строку (и, возможно, страницу) полностью?

Comment: Ну вообще надо переносить, но если есть какие идеи для случая когда можно разбивать - я бы с удовольствием ознакомился... (ибо перенос слова не критичное условие)